# Overriding a derived Event

Tags: vb.net

I  want to "override" an Event from a derived class - for example from a Forms-Control.

My actual state is, that the overriding (performed by the Command "Shadows") is working when I use the Handler of this Control directly.
Is the Control a member of a Collection it is only working with such Events which I have created by myself - if I try to use the overridden Event it isn't working. I suppose that the Collection uses the Event from the Base-Class.
Is that possible ?
And if "Yes" - what could I do ?

Code-Snippets from the described "Problem" :

This part collects the Event-Handler inside the Custom Control :

```
    Private KalenderElemente As New Collection

Private Sub CreateElements()

    KalenderElemente.Clear()

    For i As Integer = 1 To 42
        Dim myKalenderTag As New PP_Monatskalender_Tag
        myKalenderTag.Name = "Tag_" + i.ToString("00")
        myKalenderTag.ForeColor = my_ForeColor_Days
        myKalenderTag.BackColor = my_BackColor_Days
        myKalenderTag.Parent = Me

        AddHandler myKalenderTag.Click, AddressOf KalenderTag_Click
        AddHandler myKalenderTag.MouseMove, AddressOf KalenderTag_MouseMove
        AddHandler myKalenderTag.MouseEnter, AddressOf KalenderTag_MouseEnter
        AddHandler myKalenderTag.MouseLeave, AddressOf KalenderTag_MouseLeave

        KalenderElemente.Add(myKalenderTag)
     Next

End Sub



Private Sub Kalender_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    If Not KalenderElemente.Item(0).Visible Then
        KalenderElemente.Item(0).DatumsTag = 0
        RaiseEvent MouseMove(KalenderElemente.Item(0), e)
    Else
        KalenderElemente.Item(41).DatumsTag = 0
        RaiseEvent MouseMove(KalenderElemente.Item(41), e)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub KalenderTag_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent MouseMove(sender, e)
End Sub

Shadows Event MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

Private Sub KalenderTag_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent MouseEnter(sender, e)
End Sub

Shadows Event MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Private Sub KalenderTag_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent MouseLeave(sender, e)
End Sub

Shadows Event MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

Now each of the internal Controls deliver it's Mouse-Event to outside.
If I put it on a Form and write a script which takes the Event I could see that all works fine (and as expected).

In the following you see the part of the collection which should manage this Control (and others) :

```
   Public Class MessageDefinition

    Public WithEvents Control As Control
    Public HeaderText As String
    Public MessageText As String
    Public DisplayShadow As Boolean
    Public ToolTipLocation As ToolTipLocationDefintion
    Public Location As Point

End Class

Public Class Message_Collection
    Inherits CollectionBase

    Public Shadows Sub Clear()

        Dim myItem As MessageDefinition

        For i As Integer = 1 To List.Count
            myItem = List.Item(i - 1)
            RemoveHandler myItem.Control.MouseEnter, AddressOf Item_MouseEnter
            RemoveHandler myItem.Control.MouseMove, AddressOf Item_MouseMove
            RemoveHandler myItem.Control.MouseLeave, AddressOf Item_MouseLeave
        Next

        List.Clear()
    End Sub

    Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "[...]"
    End Function

    Public Sub Dispose()
        Clear()
    End Sub

    ' ================================

    Public Sub SetMessage(item As MessageDefinition)

        Dim myItem As MessageDefinition

        For i As Integer = 1 To List.Count
            myItem = List.Item(i - 1)
            If myItem.Control.GetType Is item.Control.GetType _
            AndAlso myItem.Control.Name = item.Control.Name Then
                'List.Item(i - 1) = item
                'RaiseEvent MouseEnter(item, System.EventArgs.Empty)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

        AddHandler item.Control.MouseEnter, AddressOf Item_MouseEnter
        AddHandler item.Control.MouseMove, AddressOf Item_MouseMove
        AddHandler item.Control.MouseLeave, AddressOf Item_MouseLeave
        List.Add(item)
        RaiseEvent MouseEnter(item, System.EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Item_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim myItem As MessageDefinition
        Dim mySender As Control = sender

        For i As Integer = 1 To List.Count
            myItem = List.Item(i - 1)
            If myItem.Control Is mySender Then
                RaiseEvent MouseEnter(myItem, e)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Item_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim myItem As MessageDefinition
        Dim mySender As Control = sender

        For i As Integer = 1 To List.Count
            myItem = List.Item(i - 1)
            If myItem.Control Is mySender Then
                RaiseEvent MouseMove(myItem, e)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Item_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim myItem As MessageDefinition
        Dim mySender As Control = sender

        For i As Integer = 1 To List.Count
            myItem = List.Item(i - 1)
            If myItem.Control Is mySender Then
                RaiseEvent MouseLeave(myItem, e)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Public Event MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Public Event MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Public Event MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

End Class
```

As described (on Top) the catched Events are fired with "Standard"-Controls but not with the "Customized" Control.

If I change it and build up my own Events (with different names), which are not shadowing the Events from the derived control, it is also working as expected.

Comment: This is not the proper way to do it.  Post your code so we don't have to write a manual.

Comment: The collection has nothing to do with the event.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I have committed the you as wanted ...

Comment: @OneFineDay: The collection has all to do with the problem - sorry. Please refer to the code-snippets ...

Answer (score 4):

You don't override events in .NET - you can only [override inherited event handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290043(v=vs.71).aspx), if any.

The event pattern in .NET is to create a `public` event in the base class and a `protected virtual` (VB `Protected Overridable`) method that raises that event and that can be overridden by a derived class. This method should be named `OnEventName`.

The Windows Forms controls follow this pattern, so to e.g. override when the `Click` event happens, you override the `OnClick` method:

```
Public Class MyTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If SomeCondition() Then
            MyBase.OnClick(e)
        Else
            Return 'Do not click
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Obviously you can fiddle with the `e` argument as well.

Comment: I tried this a well. There were no changes. If I override (for example) the method OnMouseEnter and don't call the base-method the base-event is still called ...!   I think it is the same as the "problem" with the Enabled-Property ...